# "Regarded as" vs "regarded to be"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, infinitives

I have come across this sentence:

> Kashmir is regarded to be the heaven on earth.

Is there a difference between that and

> Kashmir is regarded as the heaven on earth.

Answer (score 1):

"Regarded to be" sounds a bit odd to a native speaker. There is a hint of unnecessary repetition which would not be there with a different verb as in "...is thought to be...". 'Regarded as...' would be preferred.

"Heaven on earth" is a stock (adjectival) phrase; it does not need the definite article.